# How to build an Image app in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm building simple image editing app in Ionic. Primary task is to insert a logo to image selected. User should be able to move the logo, resize it and rotate it. Once the user has placed the logo, app shall be able to create image with logo attached.

My question: what will be the best approach to do something like this? Are there ready made APIs available?

Comment: Are you looking to manipulate vector or bitmap images? You might be able to do the former in JS entirely, but the latter would probably need something on the server side. (Note that this question is likely to be regarded as too broad for Stack Overflow, but you may get some hints in the comments).

Comment: @halfer Have a look at canva app . I want to build something similar where i load an image add logo on top of it. save it. (Canva app is more advance but I want some basic functionality ) . Doing this on server would be too much processing and bandwidth issue.